# Why isn't PHP processing my PHP script?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to include a calendar into my website that I am designing. Not really knowing how to create an event calendar, I chanced upon this calendar that was created using javascript. However, I can't seem to get it working.

Here is the code, in a file with an extension of .html:

```
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="date/calendar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
Date
<form action="somewhere.php" method="post">
    <?php
    //get class into the page
    require_once('date/classes/tc_calendar.php');

    //instantiate class and set properties
    $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date1");
    $myCalendar->setDate(date("d"), date("m"), date("Y"));
    $myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-01", "2011-04-14", "2011-04-25"), 0, "month");

    //output the calendar
    $myCalendar->writeScript();
    ?>
</form>
</body>
```

It appears that the PHP in the webpage isn't being processed. What's visible in the browser is:

> ```
> Date
> setDate(date("d"), date("m"), date("Y")); $myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-01", "2011-04-14", "2011-04-25"), 0, "month"); //output the calendar $myCalendar->writeScript(); ?>
> ```

I do not understand what is wrong here.

I'd appreciate any help.

Cheers,

Josh

Comment: What's the file extension on the file?  Are other php scripts in the same directory working as expected?

Comment: It would seem the web server isn't processing the file as a PHP script.

Comment: it's a html file, and my other php scripts seem to be working fine.

Comment: @user1005690 it has to be either a PHP file or you need to reconfigure your server to treat HTML files as PHP files.

Comment: @user1005690: Note that clarifications should be edited into the question, not posted as comments. Questions and answers should be self-contained, not requiring someone to read the comments. Also, please pick a [meaningful name](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Among other benefits, you'll be able to receive [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Answer (score 3):

Web servers generally won't parse php in `.html` files.  Change the file extension from `.html` to `.php`

You could force your server to parse PHP in html files as well as PHP files (with something like `AddHandler php5-script .html` for apache), but that's generally bad practice.